# vba excel - Transferring MultiSelect ListBox items and SingleSelect items in one command

Tags: excel, vba, listboxitem

I have 2 adjacent listboxes that transfer items back and forth. Each listbox has a respective worksheet. Between each listbox and each worksheet, each selection transfers properly from the first item down until the last item. If the last item in either ListBox is selected to transfer to its adjacent listbox, the item transfers to its adjacent list (and sheet), however the rest of its originating list (and sheet data) disappear *(**UPDATE:** only if one uses MultiSelect code for SingleSelect Property)*. I'm wondering if someone can see something in the code that I'm obviously overlooking. Below is my transfer code.

**EDIT:** *ListBox1* was a *MultiSelect* and *ListBox2* was a *SingleSelect* and the code was for purely *MultiSelect* ListBoxes. My working example (i.e. ListBox1 Properties) did not take that into account so I've updated the code below to reflect a transfer between *MultiSelect* an *SingleSelect* ListBoxes. I know it's a lot of code for such a simple procedure, but it's a necessity for my application, so I hope this can help someone.

**Tested and works.**

```
Private Sub MultiListToSingleList()
    Set ws = Sheets(1)
    With ListBox2 'SingleSelect ListBox
        .ColumnCount = 7
        .ColumnWidths = "0;0;150;20;0;0;0" 'contains different columns and 
    End with                               'indexing than ListBox1
' can insert error handling and message boxes here
    With ListBox1
        For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(n) Then
                With ListBox2
                    .AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(n)
                    .List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 2) = ListBox1.List(n, 1)
                    .List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 3) = ListBox1.List(n, 2)
                End With
            End If
        Next n
        For n = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .Selected(n) Then
                .RemoveItem n 'removes the item from ListBox1
                ws.Rows(n + 2).EntireRow.Delete 'removes the row from the 
            End if                              'ListBox1 source in Sheet 1
        Next n
    End With
    SheetTransfer
End Sub

Private Sub SingleListToMultiList ()
    Set ws = Sheets(2)
    With ListBox1 'MultiSelect ListBox
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = "0;140;20"
    End With
' can insert error handling and message boxes here
    With ws
        With ListBox2
            For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If Me.ListBox2.Selected(n) Then 'adds ListBox2 item to 
                                                'ListBox1
                    Me.ListBox1.AddItem .List(n)
                    Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 0) = .List(n, 0)
                    Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = .List(n, 2)
                    Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = .List(n, 3)
                End If
            Next n
            For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(n) Then
                    .RemoveItem n 'removes the ListBox2 item
                    ws.Rows(n + 2).EntireRow.Delete 'removes the row from the 
                End if                            'ListBox2 source in Sheet 2
            Next n
        End With
    End With
    SheetTransfer
End Sub

Private Sub SheetTransfer() 'moves the ListBox items to respective sheet sources
    Set ws = Sheets(1)
    With ws
        For n = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            .Cells(n + 2, 1).Value = Me.ListBox1.List(n, 0)
            .Cells(n + 2, 2).Value = Me.ListBox1.List(n, 1)
            .Cells(n + 2, 3).Value = Me.ListBox1.List(n, 2)
        Next n 
            FillListBox1
        For n = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
            wb.Sheets(2).Cells(n + 2, 3).Value = Me.ListBox2.List(n, 2)
            wb.Sheets(2).Cells(n + 2, 4).Value = Me.ListBox2.List(n, 3)
        Next i
    End With
    CheckLists
End Sub

Private Sub CheckLists() 'addtnl routine to check if listbox is truly 
'empty...otherwise header row will show up if listbox has no items
    Set ws = Sheets(2)
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2")
    With ws
        ListBox1.Clear
        ListBox2.Clear
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) <> 0 Then
            FillListBox2 'use List Property not RowSource
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("A2")) <> 0 Then
                    FillListBox1 'use List Property not RowSource
                Else
                    Me.ListBox1.Clear
                End If
        Else
            Me.ListBox2.Clear
            FillListBox1 'in my application, ListBox1 fills from a lookuplist
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you have an `end with` without a matching `with` ... i think that your code should be throwing an error.

Comment: @jsotola yes it is trimmed down code so there was some worksheet declarations in there. there are no errors thrown in the original code. I can input the ws declarations if that is helpful.  I believe I've been able to isolate the problem to the `.RemoveItem n` and `ws.Rows(n+2).EntireRow.Delete` lines. If I change it to `Rows(n)` it does throw an error on that line.